# SVG to SWF Conversion

Tags: graphics, svg, flash

I need to convert many .svg images into swf format. I can do this be opening the .svg in Adobe Illustrator and exporting to swf but this is very time consuming. Are there any free command line utilities out there that will convert .SVG to .SWF? I have already tried SWFMill with no success. I have also downloaded Ming but cannot compile the c++ source.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [svg2swf](http://svg2swf.sourceforge.net/).  Looks like the Windows binary got updated in 2009 so there's a good chance it'll work.

Comment: Over here it works fine on XP, but crashes on Vista and 7, even with Admin Privileges.

Comment: I could try that - just setting compatibility to "XP" in the properties dialog did not help.

Comment: Its work very well in windows 10, it as easy as execute a bat with svg2swf.exe image.svg image.swf