# Convert SVG to Flash

Tags: flash, svg

I have an SVG here:

*removed*

The SVG is modified with JavaScript to add the shading.

However, due to no support for SVG in IE8 and this SVG not working with SVG Web, I am compelled to convert this to flash.

I have no knowledge of flash, and was wondering if anyone could give me a brief overview of what I am going to need to do.

I insert the data used to modify the map in an object before the SVG. Can this object be sent to and read by Flash?

Comment: Did you see this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742057/svg-to-swf-conversion - Seems AI can convert the SVG image to SWF, but you'll probably have to redo all the JS in AS manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, there are no solutions for SVG+JS -> Flash conversion, bar creating it by hand. Although there are solutions to convert SVG only.

The solution I have gone for is showing a message to users giving them options of what they can use, including ChromeFrame, an IE plugin that will render SVG in IE8<.